# GPS Pseudo Range to Lat/ Lon Coordinates

Tags: c++, c, gps, lib, calc

I'm searching for some C or C++ library which can calc. the lat/lon coordiantes by pseudo range, ideally it would include sat/rev clock , ion-trop, mp bias etc. in the calcs.

Greets from Germany

Answer (score 0):

[`RTKLIB`](https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB) - An open source program for standard and precise positioning.

[`GNSS-SDR`](https://github.com/gnss-sdr/gnss-sdr) - An open source GNSS software defined receiver.

[`GPSTk`](https://github.com/SGL-UT/GPSTk) - A library and suite of applications to the satellite navigation.